# Push notification unexpectedly redirects to the appstore

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am facing an issue where the user when taps on the push notification and it gets redirected from the app to the app store. It is occurring for only a single user. If anyone has an idea for what's happening here please guide me. The above scenario isn't present on any other users .

P.S :- The user has very less space remaining on the device , if it matters in this case.